# Heatmap Kernel Density QGIS

Tags: qgis, heat-map, kernel-density

I am trying to understand the output of the heatmap tool of QGIS (kernel density). For this reason I created a kernel density map for a single point that has a projected coordinate system (epsg: 21781). I used the following parameters:

- radius: 200m
- Cell size X and Y: 5m
- kernel shape: "Quadratic (biweight)"
- output value: "Raw values" and "Scaled by kernel size" 
  => I tried both options

On first sight the outputs of the heatmap generated with the output value "Raw values" and "Scaled by kernal size" seem identical as there is **no visual difference between them**. However, at second sight I realized that **the legends differ**.

My questions are:

- Am I right to assume that **"Raw values"** refers to the *total quantity of sand in each cell* and that **"Scaled by kernal size"** refers to the *amount of sand per unit area*? (See [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/interpretation-of-arcgis-kernel-density-legend-parameters))
- What is the **unit** of the output values "Raw values" and "Scaled by kernal size"  assuming that my points are burglary incidents in a city? Am I right to assume the following:

"Raw values" = number of burglary per cell ?

"Scaled by kernal size" = number of burglary per m2 (my layer unit is meter)

- Is the term **"kernal size"** a synonym for the chosen radius (in my case 200m) or does it refer to the cell area (in my case 25m2)?
- As described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/how-to-interpret-grass-v-kernel-results) I tried to multiply the density values by the cell area and added up these values over the grid in order **to get the total sum of the original data**. My cell area is 25m2 and I firstly multiplied this value with all cell values of the heatmap produced with the "Scaled by kernal size" output value. Secondly I summed up all multiplication results: value of cell 1 *25m2 + value of cell 2 * 25m2, + ... + value of cell n * 25m2. I expected to get a total sum of one as I created a kernel density map for a single burglary incident (In case my points represented 50 burglary incidents, I expected the total sum to be 50). However, I got a much higher value (41887). Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of "total sum of the original data"?
- I expected the sum of all cell values of the heatmap produced with the "Raw values" also to equal one (= total amount of sand = in my case one burglary?). However, this is  not the result I got (1675). Why?

Comment: There is some information here that might be useful for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239279/interpreting-raster-values-generated-by-qgis-heatmap-plugin/239409